# Getiing error message 'Failed Installing JBAS50SVC' whle running service.bat file in Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, jboss, jboss7.x

I need to run Jboss 7 as service.
Followed these steps :-

1. Copied my Jboss to C:\Program Files <86>
2. Downloaded Jboss-native-2.0.10-windows-x64-ssl and copied the contenst of bin catalog to %JBOSS_HOME%/bin
3. Changes done on service.bat as per link instructions
    https://community.jboss.org/message/724488

   Changed my dir location to my Jboss bin
   and given command service.bat install

   **C:\Program Files \jboss7>bin>service.bat install
   Failed installing JBAS50SVC
   Access is Denied.
   Service JBoss Application Server 7.1.1 installed.**

   I'm not able to rectify this problem .

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be windows access issue.
Try the following:

1. Does the windows ID you are using have Administrator privileges? If no, get a Admin ID else if Yes, proceed to step 2.
2. Try to do the same but in some other drive (not c: )

UPDATE #1  : OP says he can not see the output of service.bat file

Follow the following steps

1. Open start menu
2. Search for "cmd"
3. Right click "cmd" and run as Administrator
4. type in following command 
   `cd C:\Program Files \jboss7\bin`
5. Type service.bat and observe the output

Comment: thanx for replying . I need to go with C drive only because after some days  i have to start this service  on my client side  . Actually i'm doing it for the first time so having no idea how to rectify it .

Comment: Even i tried it using right click on service.bat file and run as Administrator . But i could see only a glimpse of cmd prompt which comes and disappears.

Comment: @PathFinder : Refer to `UPDATE #1" in my answer to view the output of service.bat

Comment: Mukul :- Now i'm getting "Installed JBAS50SVC" but when i try to start it i.e service.bat start then  output i'm getting is "The system cannot find the path specified" .

Comment: @PathFinder : When are you getting `Installed JBAS50SVC`?

Comment: When i gave the command on the cmd prompt that is "service.bat install"

Comment: @PathFinder: then when are you geting the `system cannot find path` error?

Comment: Thanx ... i got the answer . Actually i forgotten to make changes in configuration files of jboss .

Answer (score 0):

On a 2008 Windows Server this occurs because you're not running the command line as an administrator. Those of us who have spent considerable amounts of time on 2003 server, and others before that, keep forgetting that your logged in ADMIN level account does NOT get passed to the command line automatically like with previous versions of Windows.

With any additional errors, past this one, I would keep going back to the service.bat file and looking at the path statements, throughout that file, to ensure that they are all correct to reach what is correct for your installation.

Also, don't forget to create a log folder under standalone (unless you're doing a domain install). Failure to do that will also cause issues as well.

yoda